# rclone - warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync, rclone

I am running a bash script that performs rclone on a directory with multiple files. However, the bash command does not finish and I get a repeating warning instead. Below you will find my bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting f2f perf tests"

source="/datadrive/0B-2500Files"

target="/mnt/perftest"

cd "${source}"

#ls /datadrive/Empty-Dir-Structure-250K | xargs -n1 -P4 -I% rsync -Pa % /datadrive/Empty-Dir-Structure-250K
rclone sync {source} {target} --transfers 256 --checkers 256 -v --log-file=/tmp/sync.log 

time /home/marcelomo/f2f-small-files-one-vm.sh
echo "rclone is done"
```

The error that is outputted is:

```
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
...
```

And this warning just repeats itself. Is my bash script calling itself? I confirm that the source and destination directories exist. In addition, I am able to move files with rsync but I get this repeated warning with rclone only.

What I eventually want to do is record the time it takes to rclone different file sizes, varying the number of parallel transfers with the --transfers argument by running a bash script.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the dollar signs on two variable expansions in the call to `rclone`. Are you calling the script itself recursively with `time` at the end of the script?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, I am just calling time once at the end of the script to record how long it takes the script to finish running

Comment: The `time` keyword takes a utility and runs it. After running it, it displays the time it took. If you call the script itself with `time`, it would obviously endlessly recurse until it runs out of memory. It would make more sense to call the script with `time` from _outside_ the script.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you much! I understand what I did wrong and I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` keyword runs the given utility and reports the time it took to run it.

Since you call the script itself, from within the script, with `time`, running the script will involve calling `time` with the script, which in turn will call `time` with the script, etc., until you run out of memory.

In short, you have managed to create an infinitely recursive script.

To fix this, just remove the whole line calling `time` and just use `time` when invoking the script from the command line or cron schedule of from wherever you call the script.

Additionally, you have used `{source}` and `{target}` in the call to `rclone`.  These should probably read `"$source"` and `"$target"` respectively.